# Traffic Camera XML feed

Tags: xml, geocoding

I was checking MassDOT Traffic Cameras site (http://www.massdot.state.ma.us/portals/0/docs/developers/trafficcams_xml.pdf), and try to copy the example XML/Summary feed (inside the link) to my own server, but it doesn't work.

I got error message "error on line 14 at column 7: Extra content at the end of the document." I wonder if this code is still valid..Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:**

It was a bit difficult to understand what you meant, but yes, the example XML in the PDF is wrong. Last line should not be `<Cam>` but the closing tag `</TrafficCams>`.

**Longer answer:**

I can just show you what I did, so that next time you can be more independent:

- checked in your PDF the XML that was having problems (I had issues to copy it from Safari, better to copy/paste here in stackoverflow, maybe)
- pasted to a XML validator (I used the first appearing in Google: [www.xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com), not good but usable), and saw that it was copied wrongly (90% of the XML was at line 8, actually)
- pasted in a text editor, to clean it (I use [www.sublimetext.com](http://www.sublimetext.com) but want to try [www.atom.io](http://www.atom.io) soon...); cleaned it, and observed the strange last line...
- pasted the new cleaned XML (now looks exactly as in the PDF) to the same XML validator, and of course the error was what I expected:

> Errors in the XML document:   15: 6   XML document structures must start
>   and end within the same entity.

- changing the last line to the proper one (`</TrafficCams>`) is now okay

> No errors were found

- last suggestion, if you use a nice editor (such as SublimeText) he will suggest you the change you've to make, when you try to edit it... simple!

Comment: Wow, I had actually missed the fact that they improperly used an opening Cam tag instead of just missing the closing tag. Gotta love that kind of documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is really working. Really appreciate all your comments. I was successfully validate XML via validator site with no error on it. However, when I load the XML into GeoRSS validator (http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/georss.html), or my site,  the messages shows unable to load the resource.  I am bit confused.. Please help.!

Comment: Hi @Peterlu12, what I see in the GeoRSS validator, "This demo uses the OpenLayers GeoRSS parser, which supports GeoRSS Simple and W3C GeoRSS" and the example in your PDF is not compliant... let me see what you can do...

Comment: ...well, I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I would parse the file from the PDF, and create one file that you can use with what you want to do, it's not too complex at all... how to do this, depends on what you need.

Comment: Thank you, phy. I would like to have GeoRSS overlay displaying on map, meaning their traffic camera (actual image) XML file showing on map. I thought I copy the script and fix it then it should be working. Since the instruction asks to re-host on web server, I wasn't sure what's goes incorrect in my part..